# WPF: Themes and how they can be used

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I've just purchased the Telerik UI components for WPF and after installation it has created a distinct Telerik C# WPF project type in the Visual Studio (2013). After selecting that project template a wizard pops up and after I complete it I see a `Themes` folder is added to my project where there is many `.xaml` files like `System.Window.xaml`.

I know that these files may be reusable themes that can style my windows but the problem is that it is the first time that I'm comming across such files. So I have two questions:

1- What exactly are these files?

2- If they are reusable styles, how can I use them. Like but adding the whole style to an empty window.

for example if I use the Office theme, does my app automatically look like MS Office ?

Answer (score 0):

Please read these documentations from Telerik:
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/styling-and-appearance/styling-apperance-implicit-styles-overview.html 
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/styling-and-appearance/styling-apperance-themes-runtime.html 
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/styling-and-appearance/stylemanager/common-styling-apperance-setting-theme-wpf.html